# How to use arecord or audacity to trigger an event in a script through a specific noise?

Tags: sound, microphone, audacity

I'm trying to set up an old computer with a microphone to have an always-on microphone and trigger a script and say send a tweet.

I want to create a log of every time a train passes, have it measure the frequency of the passing, decibel level, and duration of each horn.

Since the train horn should be at a constant frequency and volume, I think it should be able to filter out with some Fast-Fourier transformation or other included functions in software like Audacity: i.e. low-pass and high-pass filters.

It seems like arecord would be simple enough to leave running on a headless computer or rasberry pi with a mic.

Here is an example I have so far.

```
arecord -Dhw:0 -c2 -fS16_LE -r48000 /dev/null -vv
```

Also seems that speech recognition may be a good path, but that may be more complicated than necessary.

Any guidance or suggestions of the best route would be helpful.